# How to make Fourier behave like FourierTransform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm not very experienced with Fourier Transforms, so there may be something inherently wrong with attempting to do this, but how can I make the discrete Fourier behave like the continuous FourierTransform?

What is the equivelent way of doing the following with Fourier?

```
Func[x_] := Sin[x];

LogLogPlot[
 Abs[FourierTransform[Func[t] UnitStep[t], t, \[Omega]]], {\[Omega], 
  1*^-1, 1*^5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Fourier Transform of Sin(x)]

My unsuccessful attempt at this is the following:

```
Func[x_] := Sin[x];

ListLogLogPlot[
 Abs[Fourier[Table[ Func[t] UnitStep[t], {t, 1*^-1, 1*^5} ]]], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the function you would like  to take the Fourier transform of,  `Sin[x]` or `Sin[x] UnitStep[x]`  ?

Comment: Sin[x], I think. Although, if I do a FourierTransform without UnitStep my graph is blank and/or constant.

Comment: You've looked into `FourierParameters`?

Comment: For others that may need a more robust match between Fourier and FourierTransform, I offer the following: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181849/re-and-im-relationships-without-abs-among-fourier-fouriertransform-inversefour

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think perhaps you need codes like this:

```
Func[x_] := Sin[x];
tmin = 0; tmax = 10; \[CapitalDelta]t = (tmax - tmin)/100;
tgrid = Table[t, {t, tmin, tmax, \[CapitalDelta]t}];
wgrid = RotateRight[(2 \[Pi])/(tmax - tmin)*
    Range[-((Length@tgrid - 1)/2), (Length@tgrid - 1)/2], (
   Length@tgrid - 1)/2];
ListLogLogPlot[{wgrid, 
   (tmax - tmin)/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]*Length@tgrid]*Abs[Fourier[
     Table[Func[t] UnitStep[t], {t, tmin, 
       tmax, \[CapitalDelta]t}]]]} // Transpose, Joined -> True,Mesh->All]
```

[image]

Edit:

I update my codes in reply to image_doctor:

```
Func[x_] := Sin[x];
tmin = 0; tmax = 10^2; \[CapitalDelta]t = (tmax - tmin)/10^5;
tgrid = Table[t, {t, tmin, tmax, \[CapitalDelta]t}];
wgrid = RotateRight[(2 \[Pi])/(tmax - tmin)*
    Range[-((Length@tgrid - 1)/2), (Length@tgrid - 1)/
      2], (Length@tgrid - 1)/2];
ListLogLogPlot[{wgrid, (tmax - tmin)/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]*Length@tgrid]*
    Abs[Fourier[
      Table[Func[t] UnitStep[t], {t, tmin, 
        tmax, \[CapitalDelta]t}]]]} // Transpose, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> {{0.1, 10^5}, {10^-8, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @yulinyulin I'm interested, can you explain a little about how your code solves the problem?

Comment: @image_doctor, what problem? You mean the DiracDelta function?

Comment: @yulinyulin sorry, I wasn't very specific. I meant the OPs original question. The graph you've plotted doesn't seem quite to resemble either of the OPs graphs. So I was interested in what approach you had taken in your solution and how it matched the original question.

Comment: @image_doctor, I've updated my codes, I hope this will satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks, the similarity is  much clearer. I'm still interested in the method you used. Did you take the `Fourier` points and then rescale the `x` coordinate in some way?

Comment: @image_doctor, yes, of course. The x coordinate should be \[Omega], not the index of Fourier result.

Comment: @yulinyulin and image_doctor Thank you both! Now, to try to determine what the heck this code is doing! Any further explanation would be helpful :)

Answer (score 26):

I think there are at least three elements to consider here:

1. `FourierTransform` and `Fourier`, by default,   output results in different forms
2. Plotting `Sin[x] UnitStep[x]` is not the same as `Sin[x]` and behaves differently when used in conjunction with `Fourier` and `FourierTransform`
3. Plot does not handle `DiracDelta` elegantly

The signal processing form of the Fourier transform of a continuous sine wave is a single Dirac delta function located at the frequency of the sine wave.

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] 1 t] , {t, 0, 5, 0.001}]]],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 40}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the symmetric spikes around list element 2500 in the above plot of a sine wave with frequency of unity.

`Fourier` produces a result which runs up from 0 to max freq and then down from max freq to 0, consisting of two identical spectra  reflected around the centre of the list. In contrast, by default `FourierTransform` produces an expression which covers the range 0 up to max freq.

If you reduce the resolution of the time steps:

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] 1 t] , {t, 0, 5, 0.1}]]], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 40}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the Dirac delta appears smeared out across a range of frequencies, this is an effect of the discrete nature of this transform.

I suspect there is an issue in the continuous case when using `FourierTransform` in that `DiracDelta` does not resolve to a numeric value when plotting, so you don't see the spike in the continuous form of the plot.

The result you obtain with when using `Sin[x] UnitStep[x]` in the discrete case is equivalent to `Sin[x]` as `UnitStep[n]` evaluates to 1, so use of the `UnitStep` results in no modification to the `Sin` function.

In the continuous case, `Sin[x] UnitStep[x]` does not evaluate to `Sin[x]` but a truncated sine wave. Sharp discontinuities, such as those introduced by unit steps, cause a smearing in the frequency domain. I suspect this is the origin of your broad spectrum like plot for the continuous case as can be seen by examining the Fourier transforms of the two expressions.

```
FourierTransform[Sin[t], t, \[Omega]]
```

> $$i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiracDelta}[-1+\omega ]-i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiracDelta}[1+\omega ]$$

```
FourierTransform[Sin[t] UnitStep[t], t, \[Omega]]
```

> $$-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } (-1+\omega )}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } (1+\omega )}+\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiracDelta}[-1+\omega ]-\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiracDelta}[1+\omega ]$$

Which has terms inversely proportional to omega giving the long tail in your `FourierTransform` plot.

One option might be to replace `DiracDelta` with its discrete counterpart `DiscreteDelta` which evaluates to 1 at its location.

```
Table[DiscreteDelta[n], {n, -2, 2}]
```

> {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}

```
FourierTransform[Sin[t], t, \[Omega]] /. DiracDelta -> DiscreteDelta
```

> $$i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiscreteDelta}[-1+\omega ]-i \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{DiscreteDelta}[1+\omega ]$$

**Sin[x] using FourierTransform**

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 Table[Abs[FourierTransform[Sin[t]  , t, \[Omega]]] /. 
   DiracDelta -> DiscreteDelta, {\[Omega], 0.1, 10, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Sin[x] UnitStep[x] using FourierTransform**

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 Table[Abs[FourierTransform[Sin[t] UnitStep[t] , t, \[Omega]]] /. 
   DiracDelta -> DiscreteDelta, {\[Omega], 0.1, 10, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Multiple Frequencies**

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Abs[FourierTransform[Sin[t] + Sin[15 t] + Cos[30 t], 
     t, \[Omega]] /. {DiracDelta -> DiscreteDelta, \[Omega] -> 
      f}], {f, 1, 100, 1}], Filling -> Axis, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very helpful explanation. +1 I went with yulinlinyu's answer as it does a good job of matching that initial image, but really I'm now interested in knowing how to make the continuous fourier transform behave like the images in your post. Perhaps I'll be able to figure that out will all of this info!

Comment: @EmpireJones No problem :), May I ask again what your goal is? Do you want  a plot of `Sin[x]` or `Sin[x] UnitStep[x]`, these are not the same thing.

Comment: @EmpireJones  The Fourier transform of `Sin[x]` is a single Dirac delta function, not a wideband spectrum as `Sin[x] UnitStep[x] is.`

Comment: Plot of Sin[x]. When I try using the plotting method that you used above for Sin[15 x] + Sin[x] + Cos[x 30], I get only two visible points, instead of the 6 peaks that the discrete version comes up with. Perhaps the plot functionality can't pick up on the narrow point. It's also interesting that the Filling doesn't show up in your second to last image.

Comment: The discrete Fourier transform produces a spectrum {Fmax->0,0->Fmax} whilst the symbolic version gives {0->Fmax}, hence half the number of points.

Comment: The absence of points is due to the way `FourierTransform` behaves with summations of multiple frequencies.I've updated my answer with a method suitable for plotting multiple frequencies. The absence of filling seems to be related to the `ListLogPlot` and `ListLogLogPlot` functions, `ListPlot` seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The answers given so far have already solved the issue, but I think the following piece of code, based on @yulinlinyu's answer may be helpful to people:

```
Options[fourierData] = {FourierParameters -> {0, 1}};

fourierData[data_?MatrixQ, OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{xGrid, pGrid, f, x0, x1, NN, DFT},
  {xGrid, f} = Transpose[data];

  {x0, x1} = MinMax[xGrid];
  NN = Length[xGrid] - 1;

  pGrid = RotateRight[
    Range[-NN/2, NN/2] 2.0 \[Pi] / (x1 - x0), 
    Quotient[NN, 2]
  ];

  DFT = Fourier[f, FourierParameters -> OptionValue[FourierParameters]]
    (x1 - x0) / Sqrt[2 \[Pi] (NN)];

  Transpose@{pGrid, Abs@DFT}
]
```

It takes a matrix of the form `{{x1, f[x1]}, {x2, f[x2]}, ...}` and returns the Fourier transformed matrix `{{p1, F[p1]}, {p2, F[p2]}, ...}`, where `F` is the Fourier transform of `f`.

For example,

```
Show[{
  ListLinePlot[
    fourierData[
      Table[{x, Sinc[x]}, {x, -100, 100, 1}]
    ],
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[112, 2],
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ],
  With[{CFT = FourierTransform[Sinc[x], x, p]},
    Plot[CFT, {p, -6, 6}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[112, 1]]
  ]
}]
```

gives

[image: Fourier vs FourierTransform]

Note, that the grid must be equidistant for `fourierData` to work. One could extend this to non-uniform grids using an interpolation.