# Plotting the frequency spectrum of a data series using Fourier

Tags: fourier-analysis

```
testData = Table[N@Sin[500 x], {x, 0, 100}];
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[testData]], PlotRange -> Full]
```

Gives me

[image]

Which I do not expect because the Fourier Transform is `FourierTransform[Sin[500 x], x, f],`

> ```
> I Sqrt[Pi/2] DiracDelta[-500+f]-I Sqrt[Pi/2] DiracDelta[500+f]
> ```

I'm not saying that Mathematica's Fourier function is somehow faulty. But could someone please explain why there isn't a peak around 500? This is the frequency of the signal after all...

Comment: This may be relevant: [How to make Fourier behave like FourierTransform?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7016/17)

Comment: [Aliasing.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGAnL.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rahul, you have not sampled your sine wave often
enough and have introduced artifacts due to aliasing. The frequency
of `Sin[500 x]=Sin[2 Pi f x]` is $f=500/(2\pi)$, which is about 80 Hz.
At least two samples per cycle are required to avoid aliasing, hence
the default $x$ interval of 1 in `{x,0,100}` must be reduced to less
than about $1/(2*80)=0.006$.

In addition, the discrete fast Fourier transform assumes periodicity.
Hence, care must be taken to match endpoints precisely. An interval
without an exact integral multiple of the sine wavelengths will return
blurred Dirac delta functions.

I set the sampling interval to $(1/f)/4$, which is small enough to
avoid aliasing. There are an integral number of wavelengths,
100*(2 Pi/500)/4, and the endpoints are matched.

```
testData = Table[N@Sin[500 x], 
              {x, 0, 100*(2 Pi/500)/4 - (2 Pi/500)/4, (2 Pi/500)/4}];
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[testData]], PlotRange->Full]
```

Comment: Great answer. How do I get the right values on the x-axis? I understand that that the DataRange option would be appropriate. And that first I have to select only the first half of the graph. But then I also need to know what the maximum frequency is... which may be simple in this case but what if I didn't know what function I did the Fourier transform on?

Comment: @Pickett The maximum frequency will be `SamplingFrequency/2` and if you have an arbitrary function where you don't know if the end points line up, you typically use a window function to bring the end-points to zero. It sounds like you're having trouble in the signal processing part than _Mathematica_. If so, I would suggest [dsp.se] for some of the conceptual questions on DSP :)

Comment: Perhaps it's a bit of both, yes. Anyway a lot of great help here. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @rm-rf Indeed, but you have to take care that in order to get the maximum frequency at the end of the scale you have to drop the second half of the list. This also prevents the second peak from showing up. `DataRange` can be used to get the axis labeling right. Set it to {0, SamplingFrequency/2}.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries: Thanks for the $DataRange trick. Now how to adjust the amplitude?
amplitude comes with a multiplier of 20. why it is so?

Answer (score 10):

This is some code I wrote long before features like DataRange were added to MMA. 
It is part of a larger package I wrote a long time ago and it is far (*really* far) from elegant. Perhaps the OP can find them useful and with some rewriting could even make them look better on newer version of MMA.

Purpose of these snippets is to automate the scaling of the time and frequency axes based on one of the parameters supplied as an option to the AddXXXRange procedures. Starting time and starting frequency are understood to be both zero.

> ```
> Options[Domains] ={
>           DeltaT -> None, TotalT -> None, DeltaF -> None, TotalF -> None,
>       Toffset -> 0, Centered -> False,OnlyParameters -> False};
>
> Domains[n_, opts___] :=
>   Module[
>     {tos, Ts, Ttot, Fs, Ftot,
>       centered, param, timedomain, frequencydomain},
>
>   Ts = DeltaT /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   Ttot = TotalT /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   Fs = DeltaF /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   Ftot = TotalF /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   tos = Toffset /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   centered = Centered /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>   param = OnlyParameters /. {opts} /. Options[Domains];
>
>   Switch[
>       First[Flatten[Position[N[{Ts, Ttot, Fs, Ftot, tos}], _?NumberQ]]],
>       1, Ttot = n Ts; Fs = 1/Ttot; Ftot = 1/Ts,
>       2, Ts = Ttot/n; Fs = 1/Ttot; Ftot = 1/Ts,
>       3, Ts = 1/(n Fs); Ttot = 1/Fs; Ftot = n Fs,
>       4, Ts = 1/Ftot; Ttot = n Ts; Fs = Ftot/n,
>       _, Ts = 1; Ttot = n; Fs = 1/n; Ftot = 1
>   ];
>
>   If[param,
>       Return[{Ts, Ttot, Fs, Ftot}],
>       timedomain = tos + (Range[n] - 1)Ts;
>       frequencydomain =
>           If[centered,
>               (Range[n] - Ceiling[n/2])Fs,
>               (Range[n] - 1)Fs
>           ];
>       Return[{timedomain, frequencydomain}]
>   ]
> ]
>
> Options[AddSignalRange] = {Toffset -> 0};
>
> AddSignalRange[data_List, opts___] :=
>   Transpose[{Domains[Length[data], opts][[1]], data}]
>
> Options[AddSpectrumRange] = {
>       Centered -> False,
>       HalfSpectrum -> False
>       };
>
> AddSpectrumRange[data_List, opts___] :=
>   Module[
>       {n, lista, half, centered},
>
>       half = HalfSpectrum /. {opts} /. Options[AddSpectrumRange];
>       If[half,
>           centered = False,
>           centered = Centered /. {opts} /. Options[AddSpectrumRange];
>       ];
>
>       n = Length[data];
>       lista = If[centered,
>
>               Transpose[
>                           {Domains[n, Centered -> True, opts][[2]],
>                               RotateRight[data, Ceiling[n/2] - 1]}
>               ],
>
>               Transpose[
>                           {Domains[n, Centered -> False, opts][[2]],
>                               data}
>               ]   
>       ];
>       If[half, (*then centered is forced to False*)
>                       Take[lista, {1, Ceiling[(n + 1)/2]}],
>                       lista (*can be centered or not *)
>   ]
> ]
> ```

Now, let's take an example signal with components at 4 and 12 Hz, and let's sample it with a sampling frequency of 30 Hz. If we want 150 sample points, we will span a time interval going from 0 to 149 1/Fs. Fs being the sampling frequency.

```
n = 150; Fs = 30;
data = Table[.7Sin[2Pi 4 t] - .4Cos[2Pi 12 t] + .2(Random[] - .5),
        {t, 0, (n - 1)/Fs, 1/Fs}];
```

When we plot the naked data, we have n on the x-axes

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Full]
```

We can add the correct time scale with AddSignalRange, by specifying the sampling frequency used to gather that data

```
signal = AddSignalRange[data, TotalF -> Fs];
ListLinePlot[signal, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Same goes with the FFT of the sample data. We can perform our operation on the naked data

```
mag = Abs[Fourier[data]];
```

and then we apply the correct frequency range using AddSpectumRange. We can also specify we want an unfolded spectrum with negative and positive frequencies

```
spectrum = AddSpectrumRange[mag, TotalF -> Fs, Centered -> True];
ListLinePlot[spectrum, PlotRange -> Full]
```

or, just get the positive half

```
spectrum = AddSpectrumRange[mag, TotalF -> Fs, HalfSpectrum -> True];
ListLinePlot[spectrum, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The peaks are at 4 and 12 hertz.

Comment: Could you add corresponding images?