# How to calculate the Fourier Transform of a Gaussian pulse with a nonlinear chirp: Cos[ t + Exp[t^2] ]?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have an optical pulse in time domain:

```
Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t - Exp[-2 t^2] 8 π].
```

The figure of this formula is

[image]

I hope to calculate the Fourier Transform of this formula, which gives the  spectral distribution of this pulse. 
The spectral shape should be something looks like this:

[image]

But the Fourier Transform is difficult for the structure of Cos[t + Exp[t^2] ]. Anyone can help me by calculating the Fourier Transform of this 
formula? Or numerical Fourier Transform is also OK. Thank you very much!

Comment: You might try it with the FourierSeries Package?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you find such an exotic pulse?

Comment: @Jason B, Thank you so much for your good answer. This pulse is from a self phase modulation effect in optical fiber, very common phenomenon in nonlinear optics.

Comment: I'm curious to see what the spectrogram would look like for this pulse, I'm trying to work out a numeric Wigner function for it right now.

Comment: To see the spectrum of this pulse, you can refer to the book: Nonlinear Fiber Optics (5th edition)-Govind P. Agrawal, 2013

Comment: I was thinking of the spectrogram, rather than the spectrum, which shows how the frequency changes with time.  I just made a [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99679/9490) about it.

Comment: I have put some notes on numerical Fourier transforms [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558). It may be useful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It always takes me a while to remember the best way to do a numerical Fourier transform in Mathematica (and I can't begin to figure out how to do that one analytically).  So I like to first do a simple pulse so I can figure it out.  I know the Fourier transform of a Gaussian pulse is a Gaussian, so

```
pulse[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t]
```

Now I set the timestep and number of sample points, which in turn gives me the frequency range

```
dt = 0.05;
num = 2^12;
df = 2 π/(num dt);
Print["Frequency Range = +/-" <> ToString[num/2 df]];
```

> Frequency Range = +/-62.8319

Next create a timeseries list, upon which we will perform the numerical transform

```
timevalues = 
  RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -dt num/2 + dt, num/2 dt, dt}], num/2 - 1];
timelist = pulse /@ timevalues;
```

Notice that the timeseries starts at 0, goes up to `t=num dt/2` and then goes to negative values.  Try commenting out the `RotateLeft` portion to see the phase it introduces to the result.  We will have to `RotateRight` the resulting transform, but it comes out correct in the end.  I define a function that Matlab users might be familiar with,

```
fftshift[flist_] := RotateRight[flist, num/2 - 1];
Grid[{{Plot[pulse[t], {t, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
    PlotLabel -> "E(t)"],
   ListLinePlot[Re@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], 
    DataRange -> df {-num/2, num/2}, PlotLabel -> "E(ω)"]}}]
```

[image]

which is what we were expecting.  So now we try it on the more complicated pulse,

```
pulse[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t - Exp[-2 t^2] 8 π];
timelist = pulse /@ timevalues;
Grid[{{Plot[pulse[t], {t, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 400, 
    PlotLabel -> "E(t)"],
   ListLinePlot[Re@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], 
    DataRange -> df {-num/2, num/2}, PlotLabel -> "Re E(ω)"]}}]
```

[image]

That doesn't look right ,the spectrum doesn't go to zero at the outer edges.  We need more bandwidth on our transform, which we can get by decreasing the timestep

```
dt = 0.025;
df = 2 π/(num dt);
timevalues := 
  RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -dt num/2 + dt, num/2 dt, dt}], num/2 - 1];
timelist = pulse /@ timevalues;
ListLinePlot[Re@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], DataRange -> df {-num/2, num/2}, PlotLabel -> "Re E(ω)"]}}]
```

[image]

Or, if you want the power spectrum,

```
ListLinePlot[Abs@fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], DataRange -> df {-num/2, num/2}, PlotLabel -> "Abs E(ω)"]
```

[image]

Edit:
Besides looking at the optical pulse in the two conjugate domains, time and frequency, it is also possible to look at mixed time/frequency representations.  I [wrote a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99680/9490) to numerically find the Wigner function for this pulse, defined as

$$ W_x(t,\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E(t+\frac{\tau}{2}) E ^*(t-\frac{\tau}{2}) e^{-i \omega\, \tau} \, d\tau$$

and here is the plot

[image]

You can see how the frequency dips below 50 at short negative times, then goes above 50 for short positive times.  This follows from the fact that the frequency is defined as the derivative of the phase function, which in this case goes as

\begin{align}\omega(t) =& \frac{d\phi}{dt}(t) \\
=& (32 \pi) \,t \,e^{-2 t^2} + 50
\end{align}

and this is the shape of the curve we see along the vertical axis of the 2D plot above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good answer!

Comment: It would be the best if we can find a analytical answer.

Comment: For that, maybe simplify the integral as much as you can and post it on the [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) board.

Comment: For reference: `fftshift[dat_?ArrayQ] := Part[dat, Sequence @@ (Composition[RotateRight[#, Ceiling[Length[#]/2]] &, Range] /@ Dimensions[dat])]`

Comment: @Jason B    I post the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533314/how-to-calcualte-the-fourier-transform-of-a-guassian-pulse-with-a-nonlinear-chir

Comment: @J.M. I find that if I use this definition of `fftshift` along with a frequency range of `df {-num/2 + 1, num/2}` then the peak comes in exactly at the right spot.  But if I use the definition you just gave, it is shifted.

Comment: Interesting; I guess I have wrongly translated the code inside the m-file for `fftshift()`. It seemed to give the same results as MATLAB the last time I tested it, tho. Oh well.

Comment: It could be that a different frequency range works with that `fftshift` but I can't quite get it to agree.  That function is more robust, working on a 2D array with possibly odd number of elements

Answer (score 12):

Here's how to find the Fourier transform numerically (for a bandlimited signal).

Define the function (signal) of interest:

```
x[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t - Exp[-2 t^2] 8 \[Pi]];
```

Define the observation interval (this is necessarily finite, I used the values in your plot):

```
{ti, tf} = {-2, 2};
```

Now, we sample the signal with an appropriate sampling period `ts`. This must be small enough to avoid aliasing effects. Since I did not know the signal bandwidth beforehand, I had to find an appropriate sampling period by trial and error.

```
ts = 10.^-1.6;
```

The following `list` represents the sampled signal values:

```
xs = x /@ Range[ti, tf, ts];
```

The above list can now be transformed to the (discrete-time) frequency domain by means of `Fourier` function. Although you can directly apply `Fourier` to any list, I prefer to pad the latter with zeros so as to have an effective list length of $2^k,k\in \mathbb{N}$, as for that size the discrete fourier transform is more efficiently implemented (and you also gain in frequency resolution).

```
nfft = 1024;
xf = Fourier[PadRight[xs, nfft], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
```

I used the `FourierParameters` typically used in signal processing application, any other would do.

The required plot is the following (there are some details on how the `xf` points correspond to (continuous-time) frequencies, which I will not describe)

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[-nfft/2, nfft/2 - 1]/(nfft ts),
 RotateLeft[Abs[ts*xf], nfft/2]}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"f (Hz)", "magnitude"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not the exhaustive answer, but the first step to it, after which you can proceed yourself, if you like this numerical approach. Try this:

```
f[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t - Exp[-2 t^2] 8 \[Pi]];        
tab = Table[
       NIntegrate[f[t]*Cos[k*t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
        Method -> {"LevinRule",  
          Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}}], {k, -300, 300,
         1}];

    ListLinePlot[tab, PlotRange -> All]
```

yielding a part of the Fourier-transform:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good answer. But it takes me 30 seconds to run the program.

Comment: This program is short and very useful. Can we make it faster?

Comment: @user14634 I have no sure recipe. I would play with the parameters of the Method, and also try other methods suitable for the highly oscillating functions.

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) to obtain the [`Fourier`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier) transform. Recall:

$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega t} f(t) \, dt$$

This is equivalent to the partial differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial g(t, \omega)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{i \omega t} f[t]$$

with initial condition:

$$g(-\infty, \omega) == 0$$

and then $\hat{f}(\omega) = g(\infty, \omega)$. Obviously, something needs to be done with the infinite domain, and I will choose to just crop the domain. Here is the Mathematica formulation:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {D[g[t,s],t] == Exp[-t^2] Cos[50 t-Exp[-2 t^2] 8 π] Exp[I s t]/Sqrt[2 π], g[-10, s]==0},
    g,
    {s,-100,100},
    {t,-10,10},
    MaxStepFraction->.001
];//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.338992, Null}

And some plots:

```
plot = Plot[Re @ sol[10, s],{s,-100,100}]; //AbsoluteTiming
plot
```

> {0.080029, Null}

[image]

```
plot = Plot[Abs @ sol[10, s], {s,-100,100}]; //AbsoluteTiming
plot
```

> {0.060727, Null}

[image]