# How can I use Mathematica to numerically compute a Wigner spectrogram of an optical pulse?

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

This question was inspired by [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99670/9490) where it is necessary to numerically compute the Fourier transform of a Gaussian optical pulse with a Gaussian chirp function.

$$E(t)=e^{-t^2} \cos(50 t - e^{-2 t^2} 8 π)$$.

I was thinking that the Fourier transform, while a complete picture of the pulse, wasn't as useful as I would want it to be.  I think a spectrogram, showing the time and frequency information of the pulse, would be helpful as well.  The only spectrogram I am familiar with is the [Wigner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function) (useful reading [here](http://www.scarpaz.com/Attic/Documents/TheWignerDistribution.pdf) as well)

$$ W_x(t,f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty E\left(t+\frac{\tau}{2}\right) E^*\left(t-\frac{\tau}{2}\right) e^{-i 2\pi\tau\,f} \, d\tau$$

What is the best way to implement this in *Mathematica*?

My first attempt was to do it directly,

```
ω0 = 50;
pulse[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Exp[-I (ω0 t - 8 π Exp[-2 t^2] )];
pulsecc[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Exp[I (ω0 t - 8 π Exp[-2 t^2] )];
wignerfunc[t_, w_] := 
 NIntegrate[(pulse[t + τ/2] pulsecc[
      t - τ/
        2]) Exp[-I w τ], {τ, -∞, ∞}];
Plot[wignerfunc[0, w], {w, 30, 80}]
```

But I get convergence errors,

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in τ near {τ} = {-0.925724}.
>   NIntegrate obtained 2.42861*10^-17+8.97719*10^-17 I and
>   3.6945011190775015`*^-15 for the integral and error estimates. >>

Is there an option to give `NIntegrate` that makes this converge?

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=BE8588682563516B56711F02229FFD22?doi=10.1.1.57.4843&rep=rep1&type=pdf) describes a discrete Wigner transform, that I imagine would take a 2D array (`t` along one dimension, `τ` along the other) and spit out the spectrogram, but signal processing always seems opaque to me.

Comment: If you want a spectrogram, you could also consider [`ContinuousWaveletTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuousWaveletTransform.html).

Comment: @Rahul, I have no experience with that function, I'm interested to look at it. Also, I wonder how `Spectrogram` would compare to the result below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with, I'm very interested to see if anyone else has a better solution.  The idea here is to just run through values of $t$, and do a DFT on

$$E(t+\frac{\tau}{2}) E ^*(t-\frac{\tau}{2})$$

So I set up the time/frequency resolution for my DFT, using a `dt` value I know gives a broad enough spectrum,

```
dt = 0.025;
num = 2^14;
df = 2 π/(num dt);
timevalues = 
  RotateLeft[Table[t, {t, -dt num/2 + dt, num/2 dt, dt}], num/2 - 1];
fftshift[flist_] := RotateRight[flist, num/2 - 1];
Print["Frequency Range = +/-" <> ToString[num/2 df]];
```

Then I define the kernel of the transformation function

```
ω0 = 50;
pulse[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Exp[-I (ω0 t - 8 π Exp[-2 t^2] )];
pulsecc[t_] := Exp[-t^2] Exp[I (ω0 t - 8 π Exp[-2 t^2] )];
wignerkernelfunc[t_, τ_] := (pulse[t + τ/2] pulsecc[t - τ/2])
```

Then I build up the table , which is , doing a DFT at every time step,

```
Monitor[spectrogram = 
   Chop @ Table[timelist = wignerkernelfunc[t, #] & /@ timevalues;
    fftshift[Fourier[timelist]], {t, -2, 2, .01}];, t]
```

And then I plot the distribution function, zooming in on the relevant region of the spectrum,

```
parulacolorlist = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HjYmaRRq"];
ParulaCM = Blend[Apply[RGBColor, parulacolorlist, {1}], #1] &;
ListDensityPlot[
 spectrogram[[All, Round[15/df + num/2] ;; Round[85/df + num/2]]], 
 DataRange -> {{15, 85}, {-2, 2}}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ParulaCM, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Omega]", 20], Style["t", 20]}]
```

[image]

You can plot 1D slices of this for single $t$ values,

```
ListLinePlot[
 spectrogram[[{201 - 20, 201, 201 + 20}, 
   Round[15/df + num/2] ;; Round[85/df + num/2]]], 
 DataRange -> {15, 85}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"t = -0.2", "t = 0", "t = 0.2"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"ω", "amplitude"}]
```

[image]

or for constant ω, and here I vertically offset the plots for clarity,

```
ω1 = 40;
ω2 = 50;
ω3 = 60;
ListLinePlot[
 Evaluate[Transpose[
    spectrogram[[;; , 
      Round[#/df + 
          num/2] & /@ {ω1, ω2, ω3}]]] + {0, .7, 
    1.4}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Evaluate["ω = " <> 
      IntegerString[#] & /@ {ω1, ω2, ω3}], 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "amplitude"}, DataRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image]

Edit: 
In the absence of an actual discrete Wigner transform, as described in the signal processing paper above, I think this is a good solution. I was able to produce basically the same plot using `NIntegrate`, via

```
wignerfunc[t_, w_] := 
  NIntegrate[(pulse[t + τ/2] pulsecc[t - τ/2]) Exp[
     I w τ], {τ, -∞, ∞}];
spectrogram2 = Table[Quiet@wignerfunc[t, w], {w, 15, 85, .25}, {t, -2, 2, .01}]
```

But it took over 10 times as long, and I had to use `Quiet` to stop getting convergence errors.  I would be happy to hear what `Method` to use for `NIntegrate` to handle this better though.

I would also be interested to see what other forms of spectrogram would look like for a pulse like this.  I don't quite understand what `ContinuousWaveletTransform` does.  Another route would be to use a sliding window Fourier transform.

Comment: Your approach appears fine to me. I am not an expert, but I believe the "checkerboard" features are typical in Fourier-based time-frequency analysis due to the inherent limit in time-frequency resolution.

Comment: @Jason B, This Wigner function is very helpful to understand the full picture in both time and frequency domains. I  tried to run your program, but after the counts are finished, there is no figure output. At the same time, the computer is almost down (system halted). What is the reason?

Comment: @user14634, do you get a numerical output from `spectrogram[[1]]`?  Also, did you do the top part of the code or the bottom part, which uses `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @Jason B, I used your program from dt = 0.025;
num = 2^14;
df = 2 π/(num dt); ...... to ListDensityPlot[spectrogram......]. The output is Frequency Range = +/-125.664

Comment: @Jason B In[1]:  Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HjYmaRRq"]   Out[1]=$Failed warnings: Get::noopen: "Cannot open \!\(\"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HjYmaRRq\"\). "

Comment: Is the computer that you have Mathematica on connected to the internet?  Because when I type that command it works for me.  But that part isn't really necessary, it's just for the colorfunction.  I the `ListDensityPlot` call, just replace `ParulaCM` with `"Rainbow"`, or use whatever plotting function you like

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved the problem by using  Chop, ListDensityPlot[Chop[spectrogram[[60 ;; 100, 9170 ;; 13733]]...], and without Chop, the system will be halted. I am using MMA 8.0. Maybe the version is old.

Comment: That makes sense, the original list was really large for plotting

Comment: I tried to plot the spectrum at different time,  ListPlot[  spectrogram[[{81, 83, 90}, 9170 ;; 13733]]     ], I find the spectrum is not symmetric. But in the origin example, the spectrum is always symmetric. What is reason? because the sampling points are not enough?

Comment: I also tried to plot the temporal distribution at fixed frequency. ListPlot[             
 Transpose[              
  spectrogram[[61 ;; 101, {11451, 
     11852}]]            ]                      ]. The oscillation looks good. But in one pulse, there is only  three or four periods. If there is more periods in one pulse, maybe the figure looks better.

Comment: For the first question, the three time values should be equally spaced around the center, which is 81, if you want to see the symmetry.  Try `With[{n = 2},
 ListLinePlot[spectrogram[[{81, 81 - n, 81 + n}, 9170 ;; 13733]]]
 ]` and change the value of `n` to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32099/discussion-between-jason-b-and-user14634).