# Get frequency axis in Fourier transform (and save them)

Tags: fourier-analysis, rotation, frequency

I am trying to get the Fourier transform of a light-curve (with an even number of points, 300, and equally spaced in time, 6.9 seconds) and my problem is to get the frequency on the x-axis.

I can read the data (you can find them at the bottom of the post) and Fourier transform them in few steps:

```
Data = Import["/path/light_1band.dat", "Table"]
{time, counts} = Transpose[Data];
dt = Differences[time] // Short
nn = Dimensions[time]
ft = Fourier[{counts}, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
magnitudes = Abs[ft]
phases = Arg[ft]
ListLinePlot[magnitudes]
ListLinePlot[phases]
```

And I get the magnitudes and phases in which the x-axis is just an integer
indicating the bin.

I followed the explications here: [What do the X and Y axis stand for in the Fourier transform domain?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/what-do-the-x-and-y-axis-stand-for-in-the-fourier-transform-domain)

and here: [What's the correct way to shift zero frequency to the center of a Fourier Transform?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/whats-the-correct-way-to-shift-zero-frequency-to-the-center-of-a-fourier-transf/33625#33625)

But I still cannot obtain the frequencies.

The confusion arise when I have to use the sample rate (sr) which seems to be the key to convert the integer x-axis into frequencies.
From the first link it seems that my sample rate should simply be $sr = 1/ \Delta t$

But when I use the piece of code given in the first link performing the rotation with this definition of $sr$, I end up with an empty plot running from 0 to 1 on the x-axis.

Here is the code I used:

```
ClearAll[insertFrequencies];
insertFrequencies::usage = 
"insertFrequencies[fd, sr] adds frequency values to a Fourier     \
spectrum. Here fd is the output from Fourier and sr is the sample     \
rate. Note that in the second half of the spectrum, containing the    \
negative frequencies, the frequency values will not be negative.";
insertFrequencies[ft_, sr_] := Module[{nn}, nn = Length[ft];
Transpose[{Table[(n - 1) sr/nn, {n, nn}], ft}]]

ClearAll[toFreqMod];
toFreqMod::usage = 
"toFreqMod[fdata]  converts frequency data to absolute values.     \
Iinput fdata should be {{f1,y1},{f2,y2}...} where f is the frequency  \
and y are complex values. Output is \
{{f1,Abs[y1}},{f2,Abs[y2}},...}";
toFreqMod[frf_] := Transpose[{frf[[All, 1]], Abs[frf[[All, 2]]]}]

ClearAll[insertNegativeFrequencies];
insertNegativeFrequencies::usage = 
"insertNegativeFrequencies[fd, sr] converts Fourier output to     \
spectra with negative and positive frequencies. fd is output from     \
Fourier and sr is the sample rate. The output is in the form {{f1,    \
y1}, {f2, y2}...}";
insertNegativeFrequencies[ft_, sr_] := Module[{nn}, nn = Length@ft;
If[EvenQ[nn], 
Transpose[{Table[sr/nn n, {n, -(nn/2) + 1, nn/2}], 
RotateRight[ft, nn/2 - 1]}], 
Transpose[{Table[sr/nn n, {n, -((nn - 1)/2), (nn - 1)/2}], 
RotateRight[ft, (nn - 1)/2]}]]]

fd1 = insertFrequencies[ft, sr];
fd2 = insertNegativeFrequencies[ft, sr];
fd1a = toFreqMod[fd1];
fd2a = toFreqMod[fd2];
ListLinePlot[fd1a, PlotRange -> All]
ListLinePlot[fd2a, PlotRange -> All]
```

I thought that maybe the sample rate is actually the delta frequency (looking at the second link):$\Delta f = 1/ (N \Delta t)$

which, physically would also make more sense to me because I was expecting to analyze this lightcurve between $10^{-5}$ and $10^{-2}$ Hz in Fourier space and $\Delta f = 4.8 x 10^{-4}$.

However, even when using $\Delta f$ as sample rate, $sr$, I end up again with the same empty plot running from 0 to 1 on the x-axis.

What am I missing ?

Also, in the end, I would like to export the frequencies with the corresponding complex value (and I don't know how to do it because it seems to me that in order to get frequencies on the x-axis some manipulation of the plot is required but I am not sure that one can have the frequencies listed in the end...)

Here is the data, if you want to play with it:

```
 0.3450333333E+01               0
 0.1035100000E+02               0
 0.1725166667E+02               0
 0.2415233333E+02               0
 0.3105300000E+02               0
 0.3795366667E+02               0
 0.4485433333E+02               0
 0.5175500000E+02               0
 0.5865566666E+02               0
 0.6555633333E+02               0
 0.7245699999E+02               0
 0.7935766666E+02               0
 0.8625833332E+02               1
 0.9315900000E+02               0
 0.1000596667E+03               0
 0.1069603333E+03               0
 0.1138610000E+03               0
 0.1207616666E+03               0
 0.1276623334E+03               0
 0.1345630000E+03               0
 0.1414636666E+03               0
 0.1483643333E+03               0
 0.1552650000E+03               0
 0.1621656666E+03               0
 0.1690663334E+03               0
 0.1759670000E+03               0
 0.1828676666E+03               0
 0.1897683334E+03               0
 0.1966690000E+03               0
 0.2035696666E+03               0
 0.2104703334E+03               0
 0.2173710000E+03               0
 0.2242716666E+03               0
 0.2311723334E+03               0
 0.2380730000E+03               0
 0.2449736666E+03               0
 0.2518743334E+03               0
 0.2587750000E+03               0
 0.2656756666E+03               0
 0.2725763333E+03               0
 0.2794769999E+03               0
 0.2863776666E+03               0
 0.2932783333E+03               0
 0.3001789999E+03               0
 0.3070796666E+03               0
 0.3139803333E+03               1
 0.3208809999E+03               0
 0.3277816667E+03               0
 0.3346823333E+03               0
 0.3415829999E+03               1
 0.3484836667E+03               1
 0.3553843333E+03               0
 0.3622849999E+03               1
 0.3691856667E+03               0
 0.3760863333E+03               0
 0.3829869999E+03               1
 0.3898876667E+03               0
 0.3967883333E+03               0
 0.4036889999E+03               1
 0.4105896667E+03               1
 0.4174903333E+03               3
 0.4243909999E+03               0
 0.4312916667E+03               0
 0.4381923333E+03               0
 0.4450929999E+03               0
 0.4519936667E+03               0
 0.4588943333E+03               1
 0.4657950000E+03               0
 0.4726956667E+03               0
 0.4795963333E+03               2
 0.4864970000E+03               1
 0.4933976667E+03               0
 0.5002983333E+03               0
 0.5071990000E+03               0
 0.5140996667E+03               1
 0.5210003333E+03               0
 0.5279009999E+03               1
 0.5348016667E+03               0
 0.5417023333E+03               0
 0.5486029999E+03               0
 0.5555036667E+03               0
 0.5624043333E+03               0
 0.5693049999E+03               0
 0.5762056667E+03               1
 0.5831063333E+03               0
 0.5900069999E+03               0
 0.5969076667E+03               1
 0.6038083333E+03               3
 0.6107089999E+03               4
 0.6176096667E+03               1
 0.6245103333E+03               1
 0.6314109999E+03               0
 0.6383116667E+03               0
 0.6452123333E+03               1
 0.6521129999E+03               2
 0.6590136667E+03               2
 0.6659143333E+03               3
 0.6728149999E+03               3
 0.6797156667E+03               5
 0.6866163333E+03               6
 0.6935169999E+03               7
 0.7004176667E+03               4
 0.7073183333E+03               5
 0.7142189999E+03               4
 0.7211196666E+03               6
 0.7280203333E+03              11
 0.7349209999E+03               5
 0.7418216666E+03               4
 0.7487223333E+03               3
 0.7556229999E+03               8
 0.7625236666E+03               6
 0.7694243333E+03               8
 0.7763250000E+03               5
 0.7832256666E+03              14
 0.7901263333E+03             111
 0.7970270000E+03             387
 0.8039276666E+03             682
 0.8108283333E+03            1120
 0.8177290000E+03            1461
 0.8246296666E+03            1788
 0.8315303333E+03            1985
 0.8384310000E+03            2167
 0.8453316666E+03            2308
 0.8522323333E+03            2394
 0.8591329999E+03            2447
 0.8660336666E+03            2465
 0.8729343333E+03            2503
 0.8798349999E+03            2629
 0.8867356666E+03            2629
 0.8936363333E+03            2566
 0.9005369999E+03            2518
 0.9074376666E+03            2519
 0.9143383333E+03            2498
 0.9212390000E+03            2513
 0.9281396666E+03            2380
 0.9350403333E+03            2548
 0.9419410000E+03            2368
 0.9488416666E+03            2366
 0.9557423333E+03            2317
 0.9626430000E+03            2386
 0.9695436666E+03            2383
 0.9764443332E+03            2404
 0.9833450000E+03            2222
 0.9902456666E+03            2355
 0.9971463334E+03            2160
 0.1004047000E+04            2292
 0.1010947666E+04            2112
 0.1017848334E+04            2116
 0.1024749000E+04            2098
 0.1031649666E+04            2060
 0.1038550333E+04            2101
 0.1045451000E+04            1941
 0.1052351666E+04            1989
 0.1059252334E+04            1848
 0.1066153000E+04            1819
 0.1073053666E+04            1740
 0.1079954333E+04            1643
 0.1086855000E+04            1635
 0.1093755666E+04            1583
 0.1100656334E+04            1511
 0.1107557000E+04            1510
 0.1114457666E+04            1436
 0.1121358333E+04            1289
 0.1128259000E+04            1238
 0.1135159666E+04            1263
 0.1142060334E+04            1183
 0.1148961000E+04            1124
 0.1155861666E+04            1055
 0.1162762333E+04             996
 0.1169663000E+04             956
 0.1176563666E+04             965
 0.1183464334E+04             818
 0.1190365000E+04             835
 0.1197265666E+04             801
 0.1204166333E+04             735
 0.1211067000E+04             698
 0.1217967666E+04             619
 0.1224868334E+04             631
 0.1231769000E+04             624
 0.1238669666E+04             522
 0.1245570333E+04             515
 0.1252471000E+04             503
 0.1259371666E+04             501
 0.1266272334E+04             500
 0.1273173000E+04             463
 0.1280073666E+04             440
 0.1286974333E+04             418
 0.1293875000E+04             407
 0.1300775667E+04             384
 0.1307676334E+04             374
 0.1314577000E+04             359
 0.1321477666E+04             359
 0.1328378334E+04             326
 0.1335279000E+04             288
 0.1342179667E+04             259
 0.1349080334E+04             226
 0.1355981000E+04             214
 0.1362881666E+04             173
 0.1369782334E+04             144
 0.1376683000E+04             121
 0.1383583667E+04             139
 0.1390484334E+04             106
 0.1397385000E+04             100
 0.1404285666E+04              70
 0.1411186334E+04              63
 0.1418087000E+04              52
 0.1424987667E+04              50
 0.1431888334E+04              51
 0.1438789000E+04              39
 0.1445689666E+04              44
 0.1452590334E+04              30
 0.1459491000E+04              42
 0.1466391667E+04              19
 0.1473292334E+04              25
 0.1480193000E+04              17
 0.1487093666E+04              28
 0.1493994334E+04              17
 0.1500895000E+04              13
 0.1507795667E+04              14
 0.1514696334E+04               9
 0.1521597000E+04               7
 0.1528497666E+04               4
 0.1535398334E+04               1
 0.1542299000E+04               7
 0.1549199667E+04               8
 0.1556100334E+04               1
 0.1563001000E+04               6
 0.1569901666E+04               6
 0.1576802334E+04               2
 0.1583703000E+04               0
 0.1590603667E+04               1
 0.1597504334E+04               3
 0.1604405000E+04               1
 0.1611305666E+04               1
 0.1618206334E+04               0
 0.1625107000E+04               2
 0.1632007667E+04               1
 0.1638908334E+04               1
 0.1645809000E+04               1
 0.1652709666E+04               1
 0.1659610334E+04               0
 0.1666511000E+04               0
 0.1673411667E+04               1
 0.1680312334E+04               1
 0.1687213000E+04               0
 0.1694113666E+04               0
 0.1701014334E+04               0
 0.1707915000E+04               0
 0.1714815667E+04               0
 0.1721716334E+04               0
 0.1728617000E+04               0
 0.1735517666E+04               0
 0.1742418334E+04               0
 0.1749319000E+04               0
 0.1756219667E+04               0
 0.1763120334E+04               0
 0.1770021000E+04               0
 0.1776921666E+04               0
 0.1783822334E+04               0
 0.1790723000E+04               0
 0.1797623667E+04               0
 0.1804524334E+04               0
 0.1811425000E+04               0
 0.1818325666E+04               0
 0.1825226334E+04               0
 0.1832127000E+04               0
 0.1839027667E+04               0
 0.1845928334E+04               0
 0.1852829000E+04               0
 0.1859729666E+04               0
 0.1866630334E+04               0
 0.1873531000E+04               0
 0.1880431667E+04               0
 0.1887332334E+04               0
 0.1894233000E+04               0
 0.1901133666E+04               0
 0.1908034334E+04               0
 0.1914935000E+04               0
 0.1921835667E+04               0
 0.1928736334E+04               0
 0.1935637000E+04               0
 0.1942537666E+04               0
 0.1949438333E+04               0
 0.1956339000E+04               0
 0.1963239667E+04               0
 0.1970140333E+04               0
 0.1977041000E+04               0
 0.1983941666E+04               0
 0.1990842333E+04               0
 0.1997743000E+04               0
 0.2004643667E+04               0
 0.2011544333E+04               0
 0.2018445000E+04               0
 0.2025345666E+04               0
 0.2032246333E+04               0
 0.2039147000E+04               0
 0.2046047667E+04               0
 0.2052948333E+04               0
 0.2059849000E+04               0
 0.2066749666E+04               0
```

**EDIT**

I know that my question is similar to this post:

What do the X and Y axis stand for in the Fourier transform domain?

and that is why I was citing it in the first place.
I do not have enough reputation to comment on that post and in order to apply the rotations explained there to get the frequency on the x-axis I need to understand which is my sample rate and why the tries I have made are not working at all.

I hope someone will have the time and the patience to help me.
Thank you

Comment: 1. Definition of `dt` should be something like `dt = Differences[time] // Mean`. 2. There's a redudant pair of `List` in definition of `ft` i.e. the correct one should be `ft = Fourier[counts, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}]`. 3. Why not use `Periodogram` with a `SampleRate` option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the X and Y axis stand for in the Fourier transform domain?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85139/what-do-the-x-and-y-axis-stand-for-in-the-fourier-transform-domain)

Comment: xzczd 1) isn't the dt just the (fixed) difference between 2 time bins. And if not how does it change things ? 2) I tried to use ArgAbs but without success so I splitted magnitudes and phases if that was you were referring to as redundant. 3. I tried to use Periodgram but I did not get how it works, can you give me an example on Fourer results ?

Johu, I was citing already that post. My issue is that I don't know which sample rate I should use to make those rotation work. Should I write directly on that post instead of opening a new one as I did ?

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment, or I won't get the reminder. 1. Yes, it is, but your coding is just wrong. `Short` is a function for **displaying** a short form of lengthy output. Please press **F1** and check the [document of `Short`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) for more information. 2. The redundant part is the `{}`, notice the difference between `Fourier[{counts}, …` and `Fourier[counts, …`. 3. `Periodogram[counts, SampleRate ->1/dt]`, if you need absolute value, then `Periodogram[counts,SampleRate->1/dt,ScalingFunctions->"Absolute",PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: Similarly, you need to add @Johu in your comment if you want to remind Johu. Notice you can only @ one person in one comment. For more information about the usage of "@", check [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701).

Comment: When you get a blank plot, the first thing to do is inspect the data you're trying to plot. What do you get when you type `fd1a`?

Answer (score 2):

You seemed to be confused about "x-axis" and "rotation".

I feel, that first I need to explain some basics of digital Fourier transform.

```
(*Period*) 
T = 2;
(*Sampling period*) 
\[Delta]t = T/5;
(*Phase offset*)
 \[Phi] = \[Pi]/8;
(*Number of samples*)
nSamples = T/\[Delta]t 20;
(*Singal offset or "DC component" *) 
offset = 1;

signal = Table[{i \[Delta]t, Sin[ i \[Delta]t /T 2 \[Pi] + \[Phi]]} + 
    offset, {i, nSamples}];
ListLinePlot[signal, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Amplitude"}]
maxFreq = 1/\[Delta]t;
freqStep = 1/\[Delta]t/nSamples;
freqList = Most@Range[0, maxFreq, freqStep];
{realSpec, imagSpec} = {
   {freqList, Re@Fourier[signal[[;; , 2]]]}\[Transpose],
   {freqList, Im@Fourier[signal[[;; , 2]]]}\[Transpose]
   };
signalFrequency = 1/T;
nyquistFrequency = maxFreq/2;
ListLinePlot[{realSpec, imagSpec}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Amplitude"}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Imaginary"},
 GridLines -> {{nyquistFrequency}, None},
 Epilog -> { 
   Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}],
   Text["First Nyquist band", {0.5 nyquistFrequency, 9}, {0, -1}],
   Arrow[{{-nyquistFrequency, 9}, {nyquistFrequency, 9}}],
   Text["Second Nyquist band", {1.5 nyquistFrequency, 9}, {0, -1}],
   Arrow[{{nyquistFrequency, 9}, {3 nyquistFrequency, 9}}],
   Text["Signal\nfrequency", {signalFrequency, 5}],
   Text["Nyquist\nfrequency", {nyquistFrequency, 5}],
   Text["Image", {maxFreq - signalFrequency, 5}]
   }]
```

[image]
[image]

Note, that the "x-axis" is `Most@Range[0, maxFreq, freqStep]`. `Most` takes all element, except the last. `Fourier` does not give you the value for `maxFreq` as it is equivalent to `maxFreq-freqStep`. For a real input signal, all values above [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) are "images" of the signal below it, with the only difference in the phase. In the case of digital Fourier transform it [is impossible to distinguish frequencies in the different "Nyquist bands"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). For this reason it is completely equivalent to display the information in the following "rotated" form, which is preferred by people who do not know of [Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem):

```
freqList = Join[
   Most@Range[0, nyquistFrequency, freqStep],
   Most@Range[-nyquistFrequency, 0, freqStep]
   ];
{realSpec, imagSpec} = {
   {freqList, Re@Fourier[signal[[;; , 2]]]}\[Transpose],
   {freqList, Im@Fourier[signal[[;; , 2]]]}\[Transpose]
   };
ListLinePlot[{SortBy[realSpec, First], SortBy[imagSpec, First]}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Amplitude"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotLegends -> {"Real", "Imaginary"},
 GridLines -> {{nyquistFrequency}, None},
 Epilog -> { 
   Text["Signal\nfrequency", {signalFrequency, 9}],
   Text["Signal offset", {0, 9}],
   Text["Image", {-signalFrequency, 9}]
   }]
```

[image]

---

When it comes to your specific data, I am not sure, if it makes a lot of sense to take a Fourier transform of it, as it is not periodic.

```
signal = (ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#, " "][[{1, -1}]]) & /@ 
   StringSplit[data, "\n"];

ListLinePlot[SortBy[signal, First], PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Amplitude"}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

---

Why did you get empty plots? I can only guess as I can not just run and debug you code as it is incomplete. Possibly you forgot that `Fourier` returns complex values, and you have to apply `Re@`,`Im@`, `Abs@` or `Arg@` before plotting. Maybe your data was not formatted as expected by `ListLinePlot`. Maybe your "x-axis" vector still had some unevaluated symbols inside.