# Why does Fourier give me a different picture than ImagePeriodogram?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis, implementation-details

I want to take a 2D fourier transform of some data, but when I try this I get unexpected results. When I use `ImagePeriodogram` I get something that looks like I would expect. First I create some data. In this case a circle with radius 10.

```
n = 200;
data = Table[
   UnitStep[10^2 - (x - n/2)^2 - (y - n/2)^2], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
img = Image@data
```

This gives me the following picture:

[image: circle]

When I apply `ImagePeriodogram` I get something that looks like other examples I found online (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484569/fourier-transform-of-an-image-how-to-interpret-the-graphs))

```
ImagePeriodogram@img
```

[image: circle periodogram]

Now I try to do this using `Fourier`; notice the corners.

```
spectrum = Abs[Fourier@data]^2;
Image@spectrum
```

[image: circle fourier]

The specs of `ImagePeriodogram` state that it is just the absolute magnitude squared of the fourier transform, so this would lead me to the conclusion that my understanding of `Fourier[]` in *Mathematica* is wrong. I want to use `Fourier` in my code so I want to understand why these images differ. `ImagePeriodogram` is also scaled logarithmically but the pictures are still different nonetheless.

Comment: See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154060) as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two differences between ImagePeriodogram and Fourier. One you have already identified (ImagePeriodogram takes the Log of the Fourier spectrum). Second, the periodogram is shifted so that zero frequency is in the center (with Fourier, zero frequency is in the upper-left corner). Here's a way to shift and compress the output of Fourier to make it look the same:

```
n = 200;
data = Table[UnitStep[10^2 - (x - n/2)^2 - (y - n/2)^2], {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
spectrum = Log10[Abs[Fourier@data]^2];
{d1, d2} = Ceiling[Dimensions[data]/2];
xCentered = RotateLeft[spectrum, {d1, d2}];
Image[xCentered] // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

I guess there's a third difference as well, the periodogram output is scaled to lie between zero and one. This is accomplished above using ImageAdjust.

Comment: Thanks! So the rest of the spectrum was apparently hidden because the magnitude was so low. I was already questioning my knowledge on fourier transforms.

Comment: It was hidden because the range of values is large -- log compresses the range.