# How can I construct the inverse of a periodogram?

Tags: fourier-analysis

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191906/why-does-fourier-give-me-a-different-picture-than-imageperiodogram) post, instructions are given to construct a periodogram essentially from scratch. How would one write the inverse function? I want to generate a periodogram, do some manipulations, and then invert it back to 'normal' grayscale space as an approach to filtering the original image, which will help with further analysis. This can be done in imageJ using their built in "FFT" and "inverse FFT" functions. I'd like to do it in Mathematica!

Comment: I mean, *can* you reconstruct the original image exactly? Since `Periodogram` computes the *square* of the Fourier transform (the Fourier spectrum), you are losing some phase information, and so you can't take the inverse. So, you can't use `Periodogram`. But you *can* use `Fourier` and `InverseFourier`, since those are essentially FFTs in Mathematica. (Or, at least they're discrete Fourier transforms. I assume that they are implemented as *fast* FT's, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, in ImageJ they are FFTs. That's preciely at the the root of my question... how would one do this seeing that the Periodogram function can't be inverted? I'm just starting to learn about using FTs in image analysis... is there some piece of the original Fourier result that could be recalled to reconstruct the image? If so, how might that be implemented?

Comment: Do you absolutely _need_ to use `Periodogram`? Have you looked into `Spectrogram` and `InverseSpectrogram` (and the SpectrogramArray forms of these functions) ? Because that would solve the problem for you if you're okay with a short-time-fourier transform rather than the whole time domain.

Comment: @flinty TBH I'm not really sure how they are different. I am analyzing 2D grayscale images to detect diagonal patterns. The results that appear using `Periodogram` make it easy to identify the features I'm looking for... essentially two white dots positioned at an angle near the center (with proper thresholding).

Comment: `Periodogram` is just the absolute square of `Fourier`, though, so you can just use `Fourier` instead and take the (log of the) absolute square to visualize it. Then, do whatever manipulations you need to do on the FT's data, then transform back.  I guess I'm not sure exactly what the issue is.