# How can I use fast Fourier transform (FFT) to solve a PDE (heat equation)?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to solve a one-dimensional heat equation ([PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation)) with the Fourier transform numerically, in the way it was done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkA7ncY0b7I&t=538s). The equation:

[image],

is subject to the initial condition:

[image],

[image]

where *U(x,t)* is temperature, *x* is space, *a* is heat conductivity, and *t* is time.

I want to solve this equation using fast Fourier transform (FFT).

[image].

The key observation here is concerning the derivatives:

[image],

where k=2 pi/L[-N/2,N/2] is a spatial frequency or wave number. So, u(k,t) is a vector of Fourier coefficients and k square is a vector of frequency, so that

[image]

gives n decoupled [ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation), one for each these kj.

The respective code is:

```
   n = 1000;(*Number of discretization points*)
    L = 100; (*Length of domain**)
    T = 20; (*Time Integration*)
    a = 1; (*thermal diffusivity constant*)
    k = (2 Pi)/L Table[i, {i, -n/2, n/2 - 1}];(*define discrete wave number*)
    kt = Fourier[k];(*Re-order FFT wave number*)
    ic1 = Table[If[400 < i < 600, 1, 0], {i, Length[k]}]; (*initial condition*)
    ict = Fourier[ic1];(*Fourier Transform of initial condition*)
    ic = Table[Subscript[u, i][0] == ict[[i]], {i,Length[k]}];(*vector of initial condition in Fourier transform domain*)
    vars = Table[Subscript[u, i][t], {i, Length[k]}]; (*vector of variables*)
    eqns = Table[{Subscript[u, i]'[t] == -a (kt[[i]])^2 Subscript[u, i][t]}, {i,Length[k]}];(*model of ODEs system*)
    eqn = Join[eqns, ic];
    sol = NDSolve[eqn,vars, {t, 0, T}];(*Simulate in Fourier frequency domain*)
```

This error message appears:

> General::munfl: (-1.47925*10^-23+4.72292*10^-303> I)+(1.54407*10^-23-4.72291*10^-303 I) is too small to represent as a> normalized machine number; precision may be lost. General::stop:

> Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this > calculation.

How can I fix this?

Next, I intend to plot the solution by applying the inverse Fourier transform (IFFT).

```
s = Table[  Table[Evaluate[Subscript[u, j][t] /. sol], {t, 0, T}], {j,Length[k]}];(*select the solution of temperature in frequency domain*)
sin = InverseFourier[s];(*IFFT to return to spatial domain*)
fin = Table[{i, j, sin[[j, i, 1]]}, {i, Length[sin[[1]]]}, {j,Length[sin]}];
Table[ListPlot3D[fin[[i]]], {i, Length[fin]}];
```

The plot of the solution I'm looking for should be something like:

[image]

Comment: Why is the underflow an error? (It just means a result was so small it was converted to zero, which sometimes is perfectly fine.) What line of code causes the warning message, if it is important?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe this message is an error because the simulation takes a long time.

Comment: Wow what a beautiful educational video!

Answer (score 17):

There are three mistakes here, mainly related to FFT.

First, you misunderstood the meaning of `fftshift` in the MATLAB code. It's not `Fourier`, but a shift. This has been discussed detailedly in the following post:

[What's the correct way to shift zero frequency to the center of a Fourier Transform?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33574/1871)

So we need to modify

```
kt = Fourier[k];
```

to

```
kt = fftshift@k;
```

**Please find the definition of `fftshift` in the post linked above.**

The next mistake lies in inverse FFT. You've typed

```
sin = InverseFourier[s];
```

which leads to a 2D (to be precise, 3D, because you haven't yet stripped out the redundant `{}` in this step) inverse FFT, but we actually only need a bunch of 1D inverse FFT in $k$ direction! So the line should be modified to

```
sin = InverseFourier /@ Transpose@s;
```

Finally, visualization. `ListPlot3D` isn't the correct tool for the expected plot. You need the new-in-*12.3* `ListLinePlot3D`:

```
ListLinePlot3D@Transpose@fin
```

[image]

---

Just for fun, the following is a simplification for OP's code:

```
n = 1000;
L = 100;
T = 20;
a = 1;
k = 2 π/L Table[i - Floor[n/2], {i, 0, n - 1}];

(* Definition of fftshift isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
kt = fftshift[k];
ic1 = Table[If[-10 < x < 10, 1, 0], {x, -L/2, L/2, L/(n - 1)}];
ict = Fourier[ic1];
U[t_] = Table[u[i][t], {i, n}];
ic = U[0] == ict;
eqns = U'[t] == -a kt^2 U[t];
sollst = NDSolveValue[{eqns, ic}, U[t], {t, 0, T}]; // AbsoluteTiming

lst = Table[sollst, {t, 0, T}];

lstinverse = InverseFourier /@ lst;

domain = {{0, T}, {-1, 1} L/2};

ListLinePlot3D[lstinverse, DataRange -> Reverse@domain]
```

If you're not yet in *v12.3* or later, the standard way the visualize the solution is to build an `InterpolatingFunction` first and plot then:

```
func = ListInterpolation[lstinverse, domain]

ParametricPlot3D[
 Table[{x, t, Re@func[t, x]}, {t, 1.2345, 19.2345}] // Evaluate, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}]
```

Notice I've added a `Re` to remove the tiny imaginary part of the solution. (We don't need it in `ListLinePlot3D` because `ListLinePlot3D` is so clever that the tiny imaginary part is automatically removed. )

Comment: the explanation is instructive. Well, if one does not have the advanced version, is there a method to plot the result? For example in v9 or v.11, to plot the solution at T=10. Thank you!

Comment: @user95273 The standard way is to build an `InterpolatingFunction` via e.g. `ListInterpolation`, then `Plot` it.

Comment: Hi, @xzczd thank you I am not very famililar with MMA, sorry. As I am using MMA v11, to see what you are doing in the plot command `ListLinePlot3D@Transpose@fin`, I check the data structure of `Transpose@fin`. I found it is a 3D array (i.e. nested lists), the 1st dimension represents time, the 2nd dimension is for space position, and each elementary list has a complex number as its 3rd item, which has a very small magnitude. Could you please show how to using `ListInterpolation` to plot the result by updating your answer. I believe it will be helpful for many people. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user95273 See my update.

Comment: Thank you, @xzczd, now the answer becomes much more useful for freshmen!

Answer (score 9):

I would not use a numerical method if the problem can easily be solved analytically:

```
 sol[u_, t_] = 
 u[x, t] /. DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
     u[x, 0] == If[Abs[x] < 10, 1, 0]}, 
    u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 20}][[1]]
```

[image]

The result can be plotted:

```
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, -30, 30}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, the PDE problem should be solved by FFT for didactic purposes.

Comment: @user64494 Still, this answer gives an interesting alternative perspective, which on its own is plenty didactic on my book. So, +1 from me.