# Convert MATLAB code solving 1D wave equation via FFT using ode45 into Mathematica code

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis, matlab

I don't quite understand the process of solving differential equations by MATLAB. It seems that it doesn't need the explicit function to specify the required solution, but only needs to input the vector formed by its derivative into `ode45` to solve it. I want to implement the same code in *Mathematica*, but I met with difficulties.

This is the MATLAB code I want to convert to *Mathematica* code:

```matlab
clear all; close all; 
L=80; N=256; 
x=L/N*[-N/2:N/2-1]; 
k=(2*pi/L)*[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1].'; 
%init conditons 
u=2*sech(x); ut=fft(u); 
vt=zeros(1,N); uvt=[ut vt]; 
%Solve
a=1; t=0:0.5:20; 
[t,uvtsol]=ode45('wave1D',t,uvt,[],N,k,a); 
usol=ifft(uvtsol(:,1:N),[],2); 
%Plot 
p=[1 11 21 41]; 
for n=1:4 
subplot(5,2,n) 
plot(x,usol(p(n),:),'k','LineWidth',1.5), xlabel x, ylabel u 
title(['t=' num2str(t(p(n)))]), axis([-L/2 L/2 0 2]) 
end 
subplot(5,2,5:10) 
waterfall(x,t,usol), view(10,45) 
xlabel x, ylabel t, zlabel u, axis([-L/2 L/2 0 t(end) 0 2])
```

File wave1D.m code：

```matlab
function duvt=wave1D(t,uvt,dummy,N,k,a) 
ut=uvt(1:N); vt=uvt(N+[1:N]); 
duvt=[vt; -a^2*(k).^2.*ut];
```

This is what I've tried:

```
ClearAll["`" ~~ _]
L = 80;
N0 = 256;
x = L/N0*Range[-N0/2, N0/2 - 1];
k = (2*Pi/L)*Join[Range[0, N0/2 - 1], Range[-N0/2, -1]];

u = 2*Sech[x];
ut = Fourier[u, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
vt = ConstantArray[0, N0];
uvt = Join[ut, vt];

a = 1;
ufl = Table[uf[i][0], {i, 1, N0}];
vfl = Table[vf[i][0], {i, 1, N0}];
dufl = Table[D[uf[i][t], t], {i, 1, N0}];
dvfl = Table[D[vf[i][t], t], {i, 1, N0}];
eqs1 = Thread[Equal[dufl, vt]];
eqs2 = Thread[Equal[dvfl, -a^2 k^2 ut]];
int1 = Thread[Equal[ufl, ut]];
int2 = Thread[Equal[vfl, vt]];
rs = NDSolveValue[{eqs1, eqs2, int1, int2}, {ufl, vfl}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

But I can't get the correct result, I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: `[t,uvtsol]=ode45('wave1D',t,uvt,[],N,k,a);
Error using feval
Unrecognized function or variable 'wave1D'.`   what is **wave1D** your code does not run for me on Matlab. Do you have some special toolbox installed that defines this? Any way, asking folks here to translate Matlab code to Mathematica is probably not covered by the mission of this forum, as this forum is really for Mathematica programming questions.

Comment: "…only needs to input the vector formed by its derivative into ode45 to solve it" the input of `ode45` function is the RHS of the ODE system in standard form, read this post for more info: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871

Comment: @xzczd it looks like OP is using old undocumented interface to ode45 based on this answer at Matlab web site https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/517469-some-quetions-about-ode45. I see now the `wave1D` is function name in the code given but it should be defined _before_ using it. When I run their code, I run it from top to bottom one line at time, that is why I got the error from Matlab about udefined `wave1D`

Comment: @Nasser If I read it right, OP has contained the definition for `wave1D` in his post but doesn't format it properly. Just tried editing it a bit. Hopefully I haven't made it worse.

Comment: **Hopefully I haven't made it worse.** @xzczd You just forgot to add `end` to close the Matlab function `wave1D` ;)  Looking at history, it looks like OP did not have an end there. Strange, because Matlab needs an end to close function. Anyway, I had enough Matlab for one night I think.

Comment: I am sorry for didn't give the correct format of matlab code. But if the wave1D create in another matlabfile "wave1D.m", it doesn't need "end" after the function.@Nasser

Comment: Maybe you mean `uflt = Table[uf[i][t], {i, 1, N0}];
vflt = Table[vf[i][t], {i, 1, N0}];
dufl = D[uflt, t];
dvfl = D[vflt, t];
eqs1 = Thread[Equal[dufl, vflt]];
eqs2 = Thread[Equal[dvfl, -a^2 k^2 uflt]];`?

Comment: As you can see, the output result of wave1D function is a vector group, which can be calculated by ode45 in Matlab. But in mma, NDSovle can only accept the form of (eg: y'[t]=2*t) with symbols, and I want to build this form through the above code, but the result not good.@Goofy

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful explanation, which made me understand the solver behind NDSolve. But how to convert Wave1D function into an acceptable form of MMA NDSolve is the difficulty I face.@xzczd

Comment: @mozeq …See my update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but I can't get the correct result…

I'd argue it's mainly caused by careless mistake… Anyway, we don't have much post solving PDE via FFT (Is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/257740/1871) the only one?), so let me do a favor.

2 issues here:

1. You haven't correctly translated those `ut`s and `vt`s in original MATLAB code. There actually exist 2 different types of `ut`&`vt` in the code: one is for storing initial conditions, one is the independent variable of function `wave1D`. Since you've coded the system as an explicit list of symbolic equation in *Mathematica*, they need to be identified.
2. After the FFT via `Fourier`, we need to inverse it. OP simply doesn't code this part.

The following is a fix with minimal modification for the original code:

```
L = 80;
N0 = 256;
x = L/N0*Range[-N0/2, N0/2 - 1];
k = (2*Pi/L)*Join[Range[0, N0/2 - 1], Range[-N0/2, -1]];

u = 2*Sech[x];
ut = Fourier[u, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
vt = ConstantArray[0, N0];
uvt = Join[ut, vt];

a = 1;

ufl0 = Table[uf[i][0], {i, 1, N0}];
vfl0 = Table[vf[i][0], {i, 1, N0}];

ufl = Table[uf[i][t], {i, 1, N0}];
vfl = Table[vf[i][t], {i, 1, N0}];

dufl = Table[D[uf[i][t], t], {i, 1, N0}];
dvfl = Table[D[vf[i][t], t], {i, 1, N0}];
eqs1 = Thread[Equal[dufl, vfl]];
eqs2 = Thread[Equal[dvfl, -a^2  k^2  ufl]];
int1 = Thread[Equal[ufl0, ut]];
int2 = Thread[Equal[vfl0, vt]];
rs = NDSolveValue[{eqs1, eqs2, int1, int2}, {ufl, vfl}, {t, 0, 20}];

mat = Table[rs[[1]], {t, 0, 20, 0.5}];

ListLinePlot3D[Chop@InverseFourier[#, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] & /@ mat, 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-L/2, L/2}, {0, 20}}]
```

[image]

The code above can of course be simplified, but I'm too lazy to continue. Let me end this answer with a fully `NDSolve`-based solution for the problem as comparison:

```
sys = With[{u = u[t, x]}, 
           {D[u, t, t] == a^2  D[u, x, x], 
           {u == 2 Sech[x], D[u, t] == 0} /. t -> 0, 
            (u /. x -> -L/2) == (u /. x -> L/2)}]

sol = NDSolveValue[sys, u, {t, 0, 20}, {x, -L/2, L/2}]

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 20}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

---

### Update

…If you insist on solving the problem based on the same logic as that of MATLAB, then we need a solver similar to `ode45` i.e. an ODE solver taking the right hand side of [ODE in standard form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158519/1871) as the input. Luckily I've already written one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274162/1871). Let's use it:

```
L = 80;
N0 = 256;
x = (L Range[-(N0/2), N0/2 - 1])/N0;
k = (2  π )/L Join[Range[0, N0/2 - 1], Range[-(N0/2), -1]];
u = 2 Sech[x];
ut = Fourier[u];
vt = ConstantArray[0, N0];
uvt = Join[ut, vt];
a = 1;
t0 = 0;
tend = 20;    
dt = 1/20;
t = Range[t0, tend, dt];

wave1D = With[{n = N0, a = a, k = k}, 
   Function[{t, uvt}, 
    Module[{ut, vt}, {ut, vt} = Partition[uvt, n]; Join[vt, -a^2  k^2  ut]]]];

(* Definition of rk4stepfunc is not included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
step = (rk4stepfunc /. (Verbatim[_Real]) :> (_Complex))@wave1D;

solmat = FoldList[step[#2[[1]], #, #2[[2]]] &, uvt, 
    Transpose@{Most@t, Differences@t}]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListDensityPlot[Chop[InverseFourier /@ solmat[[;; ;; 10, 1 ;; N0]]], 
 DataRange -> {{-L/2, L/2}, {t0, tend}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

### Update 2

If what you want is to convert the `wave1D` to *Mathematica* code and use it in `NDSolve`, define a black-box function. I'll show a somewhat advanced way for defining it just for fun:

```
L = 80;
N0 = 256;
x = (L Range[-N0/2, N0/2 - 1])/N0;
k = 2 π/L Join[Range[0, N0/2 - 1], Range[-N0/2, -1]];
u = 2 Sech[x];
ut = Fourier[u];
vt = ConstantArray[0, N0];
uvt = Join[ut, vt];
a = 1;
t0 = 0;
tend = 20;

wave1Dcompiled = 
 With[{n = N0, a = a, k = k}, 
  Compile[{t, {uvt, _Complex, 1}}, 
   Module[{ut, vt}, {ut, vt} = Partition[uvt, n]; Join[vt, -a^2  k^2  ut]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False]]

solmat = NDSolveValue[{vec'[t] == wave1Dcompiled[t, vec[t]], vec[0] == uvt}, 
    vec /@ Range[0, tend, 1/2], {t, 0, tend}]; // AbsoluteTiming

ListPointPlot3D[Chop[InverseFourier /@ solmat[[All, ;; N0]]], PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> {{-L/2, L/2}, {t0, tend}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Because I tried to solve PDE by FFT for the first time, I didn't know whether the constructed symbolic function was correct or not, so I lost confidence. This question has been bothering me for several days, and I can finally sleep well tonight. Thanks again.

Comment: Wow, the update is very useful to understand the matlab solve progress.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a more concise code form by learning [other people's answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257740/how-can-i-use-fast-fourier-transform-fft-to-solve-a-pde-heat-equation). The original differential equation is not reduced in order.

Definition of `fftshift` is from the following post:

[What's the correct way to shift zero frequency to the center of a Fourier Transform?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33574/1871)

```
L = 80;
N0 = 256;
x = L/N0*Range[-N0/2, N0/2 - 1];
k = (2*Pi/L)*fftshift@Range[-N0/2, N0/2 - 1];
u = 2*Sech[x];
ut = Fourier[u, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}];
a = 1;
U[t_] := Table[uf[i][t], {i, 1, N0}];
int1 = U[0] == ut;
int2 = U'[0] == ConstantArray[0, N0];
eqs = U''[t] == -a^2 k^2 U[t];
 
rs = NDSolveValue[{eqs, int1, int2}, U[t], {t, 0, 20}];
mat = Table[rs, {t, 0, 20, 0.5}]
ListLinePlot3D[
 Chop@InverseFourier[#, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}] & /@ mat, 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-L/2, L/2}, {0, 20}}]
```

Comment: Adjustions for `FourierParameters` is actually redundant.

Comment: Yes, the different `FourierParamaters` have the same result after `InverFourier`.But if you want the same result as the `fft` function in Matlab, you may need this parameter.