# Is there any function in Wolfram Mathematica simmilar to fft.fftfreq (Python)

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, python

Here is an explanation of [fft.fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html)

I have data with random noise:

```
T = 1.5; n = 1000; ω = 20 π;
x = Array[Cos[ω # + RandomReal[]] + .3 RandomReal[] &, n, {-T/2, T/2}]
```

and `DirichletWindow`:

```
w = Array[DirichletWindow[4/3 #] + (RandomReal[] - 0.5)/10000 &, n, {-T/2, T/2}]
```

By multiplying `x` and `w` I get:

```
ListPlot[{xw}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-T/2, T/2}]
```

[image]

From here, I want to LogPlot FFT of xw and w but I don't get the right solution:

```
XW = Fourier[xw, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
W = Fourier[w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
ListLogPlot[{Abs[XW], Abs[W]}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {1, 1000}}]
```

[image]

or:

```
ListLogPlot[{Abs[XW], Abs[W]}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-30, 30}]
```

[image]

Closer to right solution is first plot, but I can't get symetric plot. In *python* exist *np.fft.fftfreq*, which returned float array f contains the frequency bin centers in cycles per unit of the sample spacing. Is there eny simmilar function in *Mathematica*?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are trying to do. Are you looking for the influence of a window or are you just trying to get a correct frequency axis?

Comment: @Hugh I'm trying to get a correct frequency axis. It's simmilar to my first listlogplot of XW but with peaks at x=0, x=10 and x=-10. I also want plotrange on negative x-axis.

Comment: Here is a question and answer that shows how to build the correct frequency vector: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33209/1783

Comment: Also think about [Periodogram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45506/7167)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to your comment you want peaks at -10, 0 and +10 Hz in the frequency domain. As you want a peak at 0 Hz this means that you need a constant value in the time domain. I will do this without random noise as it will be simpler to check. I will use symbols with lower case first letters as this avoids clashes with Mathematica functions. This is how I  generate the time history.

```
With[{tt = 1.5, n = 1000, f = 10, mean = 0.5},
 x = Table[{t, mean + Cos[2 \[Pi] f t]}, {t, -(tt/2 - tt/n), tt/2, tt/
 n}];
 ]
```

If you check there are exactly 1000 points. The time increment between points is 1.5/1000. In order to get exactly a whole number of cycles I have to start one increment beyond -tt/2. The time history is given by

```
ListLinePlot[x, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time / s", "x"}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we take the Fourier transform. We just need the ordinates from the time domain so we do

```
y = Fourier[x[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
```

You must choose which FourierParameters you like. This is my preference. We also have to make a frequency axis which I think is the main issue from your post. The frequency increment is equal to the sample rate divided by the number of points. The sample rate is the reciprocal of the time increment. Thus

```
sr = 1000/1.5; (* sample rate *)
finc = sr/1000; (* frequency increment *)
f = Table[f, {f, 0, sr - finc, finc}];
```

A standard plot of the spectrum going from zero to the sample rate less one frequency increment would be

```
s1 = Transpose[{f, Abs[y]}];
ListLinePlot[s1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Frequency / Hz", "Spectral level"}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, I note that you would like the spectrum to go from negative to positive values. So we need to wrap the frequency domain appropriately and make a new frequency axis

```
f2 = Table[f, {f, -(sr/2 - finc), sr/2, finc}];
n1 = Length[s1]/2;
s2 = Transpose[{f2, Abs[Join[y[[n1 + 2 ;; -1]], y[[1 ;; n1 + 1]]]]}];

ListLinePlot[s2, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Frequency / Hz", "Spectral level"}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we home in around the origin we can see we have the peaks where we wish.

```
ListLinePlot[s2, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, All}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"Frequency / Hz", "Spectral level"}, 
PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]