# Identify a note in a song using Mathematica

Tags: sound, signal-processing

I'm trying to figure out how to use *Mathematica* to identify a note from a song. The short .mp3 file found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7WrKqc1335bZlJrS0NmLVowTjg) or [here](https://clyp.it/5yh5ffly) contains a bass-note that I'd like to identify. I can find it through experimentation with a piano, but I'd like to identify mathematically.

I know little about signal processing. I tried implementing a process shown in [Plotting Fourier spectrum versus frequency of a signal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45502/plotting-fourier-spectrum-versus-frequency-of-a-signal), but 1) I don't understand signal processing and 2) the result has a lot of noise as the bass note is surrounded by lots of other sound.

How can I use *Mathematica* to analyze a short audio clip and identify dominant notes?

Comment: Well, unless you have a clear peak in the Fourier near lower frequencies, you probably can't without clearing up the audio. Do you have a plot of the spectrum?

Comment: `AudioReverb` may work as you wish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to facilitate an answer (sound - D Cord):

```
Import["D_vbr.mp3", "Elements"]
Fs = Import["D_vbr.mp3", "SampleRate"]

data = Import["D_vbr.mp3", "Data"];
{nChannel, nSamples} = Dimensions[data]

Py = Fourier[data[[1, All]]];
nUniquePts = Ceiling[(nSamples + 1)/2];
Py = Py[[Range[1, nUniquePts]]];
Py = 2 (Abs[Py]/nSamples)^2;
Py[[1]] = Py[[1]]/2;
f = (Range[0, nUniquePts - 1] Fs)/nSamples;

spectrum = Transpose[{f, Py}];

ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{f, Py}], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Power Spectrum of mp3 file", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Freq. Hz", "power"}, ImageSize -> 400]

thres = 5*^-10;
peakValue = FindPeaks[spectrum[[All, 2]], 0, 0, thres]
peakFreq = Part[spectrum[[All, 1]], peakValue[[All, 1]]] // N
```

[image]

Your MP3 file looks like this:

[image]

> {348.359, 467.031, 700.547, 932.148} Hz

Comment: `Periodogram[]` can be directly used on `Sound[]` objects.

Comment: It seemed like Fourier[] and FindPeaks[] needed raw data

Comment: Your plots might be easier to interpret if you used a logarithmic scale on the x-axis.  You could also consider putting the y-axis in dB.

Comment: I changed to a LogLog scale. @GregH Does this get you going in the right direction?