# Figuring out the frequency components using FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

The function defined below has three frequencies 2, 4 and 10. How to use the Fourier transform (FFT) to show these frequencies?

```
   myfun[t_] = 
 1/(2 Sqrt[
   2]) (\[Sqrt]Abs[
     3 + Cos[4 t] - 
      4 Cos[2 t] (-1 + 
         E^(-0.018` t) (Cos[9.99999594999918` t] + 
            0.0009000003645002213` Sin[9.99999594999918` t])^2) + 
      4 E^(-0.018` t) (Cos[9.99999594999918` t] + 
         0.0009000003645002213` Sin[9.99999594999918` t])^2])
```

Edit: The suggested duplicate deals with a simple function. It really doesn't work for this complicated scenario. Would appreciate if someone gets it done.

Comment: No, it has more than 3 frequencies due to the present of the factor `E^(-0.018` t)` and the square roots.

Comment: Thanks,@HenrikSchumacher. Could this be shown using FFT?

Comment: Yes. You just have to sample `myfun` on an evenly spaced grid from `-Pi` to Pi` and apply `Fourier`.

Comment: Kindly post as an answer.

Comment: That method doesn't really work.

Comment: Try [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45502/plotting-fourier-spectrum-versus-frequency-of-a-signal?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/whats-the-correct-way-to-shift-zero-frequency-to-the-center-of-a-fourier-transf?noredirect=1&lq=1) or...

Comment: Why doesn't the method suggested in the previous post work for you? I tried it myself and it seemed to work fine, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you want. If you want to increase the resolution, you can increase the maximum time as well as the number of samples per second when you are sampling the function.

Comment: Be kind and post it if you think it works fine. I do not find the expected frequencies.

Comment: @Patrick. Note that your frequencies will not be 2, 4, and 10 as you think. First of all, since the `Sin[10 t]` is squared, the relevant angular frequency is actually 20. Second of all, those are particular *angular* frequencies that show up. Instead, you should see dominant peaks at $2/2\pi$, $4/2\pi$, and $20/2\pi$, which you will see if you use one of the linked answers. The one using `Periodogram' is easy to use, and the other one shows the best way to use `Fourier` (the FFT) to get a power spectrum.

Answer (score 6):

First lets plot your function to see what it looks like.

```
Plot[myfun[t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is only between 0 to 100 seconds. What we see is some very high frequencies but also a constant frequency which we can estimate at about 0.3 Hz. If we plot at later times

```
Plot[myfun[t], {t, 500, 600}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that the starting high frequencies have died away and the frequency at about 0.3 Hz remains.

Now we can do a Fourier analysis. As you have some high frequencies we need to sample at a very fast sample rate. I have guessed at the sample rate but hope it is good enough.

```
sr = 100;  (* Sample rate *)
data = Table[myfun[t], {t, 0, 1000, 1/sr}];
nn = Length@data
```

Plotting again shows that I seem to have captured the high frequency data

```
ListLinePlot[data[[1 ;; Round[100 sr]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should probably check by looking at a shorter time interval.

Now for the Fourier analysis.

```
ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
freqs = Table[f, {f, 0, sr (nn - 1)/nn, sr/nn}];
```

The second line of code is to make the frequencies that correspond to the data in the Fourier transform. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85167/12558) for details.

```
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{freqs, Abs[ft]}][[1 ;; 10000]], 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see a dominant peak at about 0.3 Hz and lots of other peaks that make up your high frequencies.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Periodogram and Spectrogram are also useful:

```
data = Table[myfun[t], {t, 0, 100000, .1}];
Periodogram[data, SampleRate -> 10, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Hz", "dB"}]
```

[image]

```
Spectrogram[data, SampleRate -> 10, PlotRange -> {0, .5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Hz"}]
```

[image]