# Why does Fourier give a shifted frequency?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have a signal that I want to identify the frequencies in it, I used the Fourier function but I can't get the frequency correctly. Here is a simplified example:

```
dt = 1/100;
ls = Table[0.1 Cos[30 x] + 2 Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 200 dt, dt}];
ListPlot[ls, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

and the Fourier transform

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[ls]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{30/(2 π)}, None}]
```

[image]

Why do I get the peak not at the original frequency 30/(2Pi), but with a frequency shift? Did I make a terrible mistake?
What's the correct way to recover the original frequency using Mathematica's signal processing features?

I tried to padding zeros but still have a frequency shift.

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[PadRight[ls, 2000]]]^2, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, .1}}, DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{30/(2 π)}, None}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

I'm still not convinced that this problem is due to that there are too few periods contains in the signal, nor that number of periods contained in the signal is not an integer. Consider this signal

```
ls = Table[0.1 Cos[30 x], {x, 0, 200 dt, dt}];
```

it contains the same number of periods and the number of periods is not an integer, it gives a peak that are not centered,

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[ls]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{30/(2 π)}, None}]
```

[image]

but padding zero helps

```
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[PadRight[ls, 2000]]]^2, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, .1}}, DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
 Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{30/(2 π)}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plotting the frequency spectrum of a data series using Fourier](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18082/plotting-the-frequency-spectrum-of-a-data-series-using-fourier)

Comment: @chuy I don't think it's a duplicate, the post you linked is because of aliasing where the sample rate is not high enough to cover the signal frequency, here it's not. You can see that by comparing the [plot of the data in that question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OGAnL.png) to the first plot in this question.

Comment: When the waveform has very few periods, the magnitude of the Fourier transform depends on the phase of the `Cos[30 x]`. Try `Cos[30 x + Pi]` and you will see the peak *above* the expected frequency.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, actually it was the second part in the answer: "in addition, the discrete fast Fourier transform assumes periodicity."

Comment: @chuy In the second part, I think the point is that if a signal contains partial periods, then there is always a convolution with the Fourier transform of the signal duration involved, which introduced a peak width in the Fourier transform results. But that's not the case here. As here my question is about the central frequency. Plus, in a real situation, it's difficult to ensure the restriction that every signal should contain integer number of periods.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I think you are right : your frequency error is not due to a lack of periods in the waveform (with 10 periods, the phenomenon is negligible)

Comment: You are sampling your squared sine less than a single period. This means that your spectrum will be samples of some deltas convolved with a fat `Sinc` (and the samples won't happen to fall on the sinc's zeros). Given that `Sinc`'s fatness, the fact that your sin has high amplitude compared to the cos, that the cos frequency isn't very far away from the sin's (just about 9 sinc's lobes away), that the sinc decays slowly (compared to other common window transforms), that sinc's lobe is comparable to the cos's and makes it appear shifted

Comment: Uhh, almost too long for a comment. So, using a number of samples that makes a near integer number of sin's to fit fixes it. Using a lower sin amplitude. Windowing with some window with smaller secondary lobes. Also, in theory your data range should go up to slightly less than 1/dt, but that won't make a difference (and if it did, it would be in the wrong direction)

Comment: @Rojo That answers my questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the frequency mismatch arises because the endpoints of your 200 point series are offset. The first point has amplitude 0.1, the last 1.5584. As others mention, the Fourier transform assumes periodicity. So the signal you are transforming has a sine component, a cosine component, and a step function offset of the first and last points. The Fourier transform of a step function is

```
FourierTransform[UnitStep[t], t, x]
```

which evaluates to roughly $1/x+\delta[x]$, where $\delta$ is the delta function, and $x$ is the frequency variable. This spectrum is peaked at $x=0$ and drops off with increasing $|x|$. Thus, the time-domain step function contributes a *sloping* frequency spectrum to your frequency-domain delta-functions from the sine and cosine. The sloped spectrum increases the amplitudes of frequencies less than $30/(2\pi)$ more than the amplitudes of frequencies greater than $30/(2\pi)$.

If your signal were sampled with 297 points, the first and last points would be 0.1 and 0.100489. With the endpoints roughly matched, the spectrum peak is not shifted from the expected $30/(2\pi)$.

**EDIT**

1) You comment that the partial period only gives the finite peak width. With respect, you cannot ignore the frequency response of the step function inherent in your data. It is **in** the spectrum, period. The "Edit" example you give has a smaller step-function offset, so its influence is reduced.

```
Plot[Abs[FourierTransform[UnitStep[t], t, w]]^2, {w, -1, 1}]
```

2) As you say, in a "real situation" signals cannot always contain an integer number of periods. In practice, signals are tapered on both ends with, for example, a cosine-squared bell function to eliminate step-function artefacts. Thus, an integral number of periods is not required. When I taper your 200 point function with the following very rough function, the DFT amplitudes at the sampled frequencies on either side of $f=30/(2\pi)$ are much more equal.

```
Block[{dt=1/100, ls, a=0.2, nn=201},
   ls = Table[0.1 Cos[30 x], {x, 0, 200 dt, dt}];
   ls = ls * Table[(1 - a)/2 - 1/2 Cos[2 \[Pi] n/(nn - 1)] + 
                   a/2 Cos[4 \[Pi] n/(nn - 1)], {n, 0, 200}];
   ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[PadRight[ls,2000]]]^2, 
      PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,0.015}}, DataRange->{0, 1/dt}, 
      Joined->True, FrameLabel->{"Frequency","Intensity"}, 
      Mesh->All, MeshStyle->Red, GridLines->{{30/(2 \[Pi])},None}] ]
```

3) The DFT does what it does, and its answers are not "wrong"; however, its answers require some interpretation in light of limited data, non-integral periods, and mismatched endpoints. (Thank you @LeoFang)

Comment: I think partial period in the signal only gives the finite width of the peak, see my comments under my question and the other answer. Moreover, if this is because of the partial period, how can I explain that the signal in my "Edit" gives the correct frequency after padding zeros? Its end point is also not perfectly lined up. Plus, in a real situation, it's difficult to ensure the restriction that every signal should contain integer number of periods. Does that mean Fourier transform always give "wrong" results in identifying the frequencies?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kenny, I'm sorry to give you a downvote but I think your explanation is wrong. @xslittlegrass, please take a look again at both James Cunnane's and my answers below. In my answer I did capture the two frequencies 2/2Pi (not 1/2Pi because it's sine square) and 30/2Pi without any shift if you further increase duration from Pi to 10Pi.

Comment: @LeoFang I guess maybe your are saying the same thing. Half of a cycle of the low frequency in the signal gives a step function, which creates spectrum that interfere with the high frequency peak. I upvoted your answer too :)

Comment: @LeoFang I'm sorry about your downvote too, especially since you do not say
how or why my explanation is wrong. I will not downvote your answer, you
could do that yourself because both our explanations are the same, as
stated by xslittlegrass in the comment above. You and I both suggest sampling
more points to solve the problem. In my case 297 points, in yours 314, a
trivial difference caused by the low-amplitude higher-frequency component.
Can you see that, for harmonic signals, an incomplete period is the same as
mismatched endpoint amplitudes?

Comment: @LeoFang Arbitrary resampling of a signal is not
always possible in the real world. Given only the original 201-point signal,
tapering removes the problem, as I suggested, as JamesCunnane suggested
in a comment (recommending trend removal as well), and as Mr.Wizard suggested
in an answer. Again, this does not mean your answer is wrong.

Comment: @KennyColnago, Sorry for my late reply. I was focusing on solving a tough problem last month. I sit down and think about it throughly, and I think your comments above make sense and I owe you an apology for the downvote. Unfortunately the system does not allow me to upvote it unless you edit the post, so if you'd like you could make a tiny change of it and I'll upvote.

Comment: @KennyColnago For my defense I'd like to tell you what I was thinking back that time. I thought using either windowing or zero padding was way too complicated for such a simple problem. Like you said, "arbitrary resampling of a signal is not always possible in the real world", but I thought the OP apparently did not even recognize the importance of choosing a correct time period T to resolve the underlying frequency components.

Comment: @KennyColnago, upvoted. :)

Answer (score 10):

Fourier Transform is based on assumptions of periodicity related to the duration of the data.  If you choose a misleading duration, you will get misleading results.

The duration (200 dt) of your array ls is not a multiple of the periods of your waveforms; this introduces artefacts arising from the Fourier transform of the 'top hat' function of width (200 dt).  No amount of padding will remove this completely.

Try with the duration of ls much closer to a multiple of the duration of the fundamental; results will be closer to expected.

A dramatic improvement is seen with 314 points, i.e. about 100 times \Pi

Comment: I don't think it's because that the signal contains too few periods, see my update.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I think it's not your periods are too few, it's because the *total duration of your data* ($L$) is not exactly an **integer multiple** of the *duration of one period* of the signal ($T$). $L/T \notin \mathbb N$

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I deleted my misleading comment. A more precise explanation is that you have to fine-tune your duration T (in this case, 200dt) such that an integer multiple of 1/T exactly locates at the frequency you're looking at (in this case, 30/2Pi) in the Fourier spectrum, otherwise the "energy" would be split into adjacent frequencies, which can be seen by simply increasing T to an arbitrary value (so that you have finer grid in the spectrum).

Comment: @Silvia Leo Fang I think L/T is not an integer only gives the **finite width of the peak**, but not a frequency shift. For the signal in my update, that ratio is also not an integer, but the the frequency in the spectrum is correct.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I see your point now. Need to go to sleep, but I suspect you incorrectly specified the `DataRange` with your padded data...

Comment: @Silvia I think the exact range should be {0, (N-1)/(N dt)}, according to [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33625/1364). But the difference to {0,1/dt} can be ignored. Good night :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I disagree. See my answer below. The width of the peak is solely controlled by 1/T (btw, I noticed that I used T for total duration, which is different from the T in Silvia's comment).

Comment: @MrWizard has very sensibly suggested windowing.  Now here is the pedagogical bit: windowing helps with the sidelobe effect, and also reduces the size of the sawtooth problem arising from the linear trend / offset of the data.

Comment: And furthermore: You would do even better by also preprocessing the original data to remove offset and linear trend; this gets rid of the discontinuity effects noted by @KennyColnago. But need to be careful if you are doing frame-based Fourier Transform; don't throw away the per-frame offsets, as they contain information about frequencies below the lowest frequency discernible in a single frame.

Comment: @JamesCunnane Yes, I tried something like `ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[PadRight[ls - ExponentialMovingAverage[ls, 0.1], 2000]]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, .1}}, DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, GridLines -> {{30/(2 Pi)}, None}, Joined -> True]` and it works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A windowing function should help:

```
ls2 = (ls - Mean[ls]) Array[TukeyWindow, Length@ls, {{-0.5, 0.5}}];

ListLinePlot[ls2]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[ls2]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 GridLines -> {{30/(2 π)}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you have a look on the following question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195288/problem-with-inversefourier-of-a-2d-fft-of-a-non-squared-image

Answer (score 3):

This is just a long supplement comment to @James Cunnane's answer which is correct. Try

```
dt = 1/100;
T=Pi;
ls = Table[0.1 Cos[30 x] + 2 Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, T, dt}];
ListPlot[ls, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[ls]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}, 
DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{30/(2 \[Pi])}, None}, 
Frame -> True, Joined -> True]
```

[image: output]

Note the only thing changed is the duration T whose inverse (1/Pi) defines the grid size in the Fourier spectrum. As a result, the desired frequency 30/Pi is now an integer multiple of the grid size and therefore can be captured correctly.

**EDIT**

Because the grid size 1/T=1/Pi is not fine enough, it is less easier to observe the lower frequency 2/2Pi (not 1/Pi because it's a sine square). Try to increase T to a larger value would resolve this issue if you like:

```
dt = 1/100;
T = 5 Pi;
ls = Table[0.1 Cos[30 x] + 2 Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, T, dt}];
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[ls]]^2, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, 
DataRange -> {0, 1/dt}, FrameLabel -> {"Frequency", "Intensity"}, 
Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, GridLines -> {{2/(2 \[Pi])}, None}, 
Frame -> True, Joined -> True]
```

[image: output2]

Last comment: The reason you see a very high peak at zero frequency is due to the constant term when you write `Sin[x]^2` as `(1 - Cos[2 x])/2`.