# Problem with InverseFourier of a 2d FFT of a non-squared image

Tags: image-processing

I have the following 8bit grey scale image:

[image]

The 2d FFT of this image, showing the color coded `Abs[fft]` values, is:

[image]

The code to obtain the FFT image is:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA0nv.png"];

dimimg = ImageDimensions[img];
rdimimg = Reverse[dimimg];

fft = Fourier[ImageData[img]];
fftRotated = RotateLeft[fft, Floor[Dimensions[fft]/2]];

fftAbsData = Abs[fftRotated];

minc = 140;
myColorTable = 
  Flatten@{Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Orange}, x]}, {x, 
      1/minc, 1, 1/minc}], 
    Table[{Blend[{Orange, Red, Darker@Red}, x]}, {x, 1/(256 - minc), 
      1, 1/(256 - minc)}]};

g = Colorize[
   ImageResize[Image[fftAbsData], {rdimimg[[1]], rdimimg[[2]]}], 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[myColorTable, #] &)];

xfrequencies = (Range[rdimimg[[1]]] - Round[rdimimg[[1]]/2])/
   rdimimg[[1]];
yfrequencies = (Range[rdimimg[[2]]] - Round[rdimimg[[2]]/2])/
   rdimimg[[2]];

minmaxxf = MinMax[xfrequencies];
minmaxyf = MinMax[yfrequencies];

dy = minmaxyf[[2]] - minmaxyf[[1]];
dx = minmaxxf[[2]] - minmaxxf[[1]];

scaleFactor = 600;

imagefft = ImageResize[g, scaleFactor*{dx, dy}]
```

**Questions:**

Now I would like to cut out the red ring and make a backward FFT to see
which objects of the original image belong to the high amplitude fft data, seen in red.

**How can I cout out a circular region in the fft image?**

Even without cutting out a part I am not able to reproduce the original image from `fft`:

```
inverse=Image[InverseFourier[fft]]
```

gives me:

[image]

**Why does `InverseFourier` not reproduce the original image?**

Comment: You may ctry to create a ellipsoidic annulus-shaped mask by something along the lines of `DiskMatrix[{R1, R2}, {n1, n2}] - DiskMatrix[{r1, r2}, {n1, n2}]`. Here, `n1` and `n2` are the image dimensions, `R1`, `R2` are the outer radii  and `r1`, r2` are the inner radii of the annulus. And of course, by `InverseFourier` but I expect you knew it already ;)

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thank you for the hint about how to cut out the annulus.

Comment: You're welcome. =)

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: I have a problem with `InverseFourier´ (see above). Do you have an idea where I make an error?

Comment: Try `Chop`, you can see that it works by checking that `img - Image[Chop@InverseFourier[fft]]` is a completely black image. (Alternately, you can call `Max` on the result and check that the largest value is on the order of machine precision, 10^(-16))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your image, you can first check that `InverseFourier` does indeed reproduce the original image:

```
inverse = Image[Chop@InverseFourier[fft]];
ImageDistance[inverse, img]
```

returns  3.90437*10^-6

> Now I would like to cut out the red ring and make a backward FFT to
>   see which objects of the original image belong to the high amplitude
>   fft data, seen in red.

Well, don't expect "objects" - the Fourier transform is a global operation, so you'll basically see the result of a linear (bandpass) filter by masking in the FFT domain.

But you can try easily enough. Simply create a binary mask:

```
mask = Array[Boole[.15 < Norm[{##}] < .25] &, 
   Dimensions[fftRotated], {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}];

HighlightImage[Image[Rescale@Log[Abs@fftRotated]], Image[mask]]
```

[image]

Multiply it with the FFT and apply inverse transform:

```
fftMasked = RotateRight[mask*fftRotated, Floor[Dimensions[fft]/2]];
```

And display the real part of the result:

```
Image[Rescale[Chop[Re@InverseFourier[fftMasked]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the solution. I found out the the frequencies of the fft image are ALWAYS from -0.5 to 0.5, on both axes. Can you explain how I can interpret this value?